# How to use the Django admin template for a form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I want to use the existing Django Admin template for a form of my own. The situation is like there are two models. say A and B and I want a form that displays the details about both the models in a songle form of my own. So I am using a `ModelForm`. But I want to use the templates from the `django admin`. How can I do that?

Comment: You can extends from (http://pastebin.com/fT69Tuku) admin/base_site.html sorry if this is in spanish

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Unknown paste id?

Comment: @IndaradhanushGupta Now?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to override the admin interface. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Answer (score 0):

Would a [Class-based generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects) work for you?

Comment: Not sure about that. Overriding the admin feels good. But how do you think I can use both the models in one form? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can use two models in one form but it brings up questions on functionality.  Mainly, how do you want to interact with two models on one page?  You should try and find a form that mimics the one you want and then copy it.

Comment: Im considering over riding the model admin to include the functionalities of two models into one ModelAdmin. How can this be done? Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203589/how-may-i-overrride-the-modeladmin-so-that-it-displays-components-of-two-models

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question.  Post your models and code, and ask a more specific question.