# How may I overrride the ModelAdmin so that it displays components of two models?

Tags: python, django, django-modeladmin

I want to `override` the `ModelAdmin`. But I want to include the functionalities of `two models` into one. However I'm not considering merging the two models into one. Is there any other way in which I can `override` it and include the functionalities of both of my `models` into one `ModelAdmin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a relation between your models. Take a look to *InlineModelAdmin*:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

Comment: Okay. Say I have the models `ModelA` and `ModelB`. `ModelB` has a `foreign key` to `ModelA`.

Comment: in this case you can use *Inline*.